# Random pick TFS Build Agents

Tags: tfs

We have 1 Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 3 and 3 different build agents configuered. I've noticed that TFS picks the same build agent after when a project have to build. My question is there an option to pick a build agent randomly?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't an option to set that to pick a build agent randomly.

For now, in TFS 2017 it picks the agent in the order that they are registered if the agents are all idle when a build is queued, rather than randomly selecting an agent.

Set `Build Agent Priority` is an good idea, and there is a [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17701630-build-agent-priority) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve it in future.

Currently as a workaround, you can set the [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#demands) in build definitions to force building with the specific agents.

To do that, you can reference below articles:

- [How to send TFS build to a specific agent or server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2017/02/08/how-to-send-tfs-build-to-a-specific-agent-or-server/)
- [Build vNext, distributing load to different agents](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/06/build-vnext-distributing-load-to-different-agents/)